# QGIS: ESRI shapefile .shp no longer appears in list of file types under Add Vector Layer

Tags: qgis, vector, layers

I recently installed QGIS 2.18.4 after using ArcMap for many years. I want to add several existing ESRI shapefiles (.shp) created in Arc, to a QGIS project. To add a new layer in QGIS, I select the "Add Vector Layer" button and then click "Browse" to go find the layer. Then I navigate to the proper folder. However, **the drop down menu at the lower right of the "Open an OGR Supported Vector Layer" window does not include ESRI Shapefile** on the list. The first one on the list is GeoJSON. Everything after "G" appears to be okay (all the way down to "X-Plane/Flightgear") but any file formats from A through F have been cut from the list. Since "ESRI" starts with "E" it does not show up on the list. Strange thing is when I first installed QGIS, ESRI Shapefile appeared on this list. **So I must have accidently done something to change how that list is populated and I want to know how to change it back**.

If I type in the name of the ESRI shapefile that I know is in the folder, it and all other files starting with those letters appears in the prompt window that appears. And QGIS will correctly load the Shapefile. However, I want to be able to see all those ESRI Shapefiles without having to know and type in the first letter so it will appear in the prompt. I want it to appear in the file type drop down (or drop up?) menu.

Answer (score 3):

You were fooled by Windows Explorer UI and the very long "X-Plane" entry. Just scroll up in the file type list using cursor up key or mouse wheel.

Comment: Okay, that's it. Mousing up doesn't show them but scrolling the mouse wheel does. Also the keyboard arrows work. I had selected an .XLSX file before and so that was the default list item it started with.  Many thanks!