# Shapefile missing from 'Add Vector Layer' file type in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Ran into a bizarre problem in QGIS ( 2.18.4). I am trying to load a shapefile with extension *.shp.

When I choose Add Vector Layer -> Browse, I do not see any option to load ESRI Shapefiles.

[image]

I must be missing something very elementary.

Comment: Does drag-and-drop still work? Also, did you try the method posted in this closely-related question: [QGIS: ESRI shapefile .shp no longer appears in list of file types under Add Vector Layer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232188/qgis-esri-shapefile-shp-no-longer-appears-in-list-of-file-types-under-add-vect)

Comment: Thanks !!! This worked from your recommended post .... "You were fooled by Windows Explorer UI and the very long "X-Plane" entry. Just scroll up in the file type list using cursor up key or mouse wheel"

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working. I haven't come across that problem before as there's always a scroll bar for me :)